How to cache a file in order to upload it and avoid the ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_CHANGED error?
I have a Vue component that allows the user to upload a CSV file, preview the results, and then confirm the changes that will be done in the system.
Sometimes the browser gives me the error: "ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_CHANGED".
How to properly repro: upload file cause the error "net::ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_CHANGED"
I want a way to cache the uploaded file in the front-end until the whole process is finished.

I could make it work by caching the selected file as a ArrayBuffer using FileReader:
<input type="file" @change="onInputFileChange" ref="inputTypeFile" />

onInputFileChange() {
  // caching the selectedFile data to prevent ERR_UPLOAD_FILE_CHANGED error
  const selectedFile = this.$refs.inputTypeFile.files[0];
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = () => this.cachedFile = fr.result;
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(selectedFile);
},

onSubmitClick() {
  // [...]
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("csvFile", new Blob([this.cachedFile], {type: "text/csv"}));
  // [...]
}

